# OpenERP - Page referenced in xpath not found in parent view

Tags: odoo

I have the following code in my xml view file that inherits from another view:

```
<xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Accounting']/group" position="replace"></xpath>
```

but it gives me the error:
Element `"'<xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Accounting']/group">'"` cannot be located in parent view

although the 'Accounting' tab is in the parent view. What I am doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Here is the view I inherited from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="product_template_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.template.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="priority">5</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <page string="Sales" position="after">
                    <page string="Accounting" groups="account.group_account_invoice">
                        <group>
                            <label for="categ_id" string="Internal Category"/>
                            <div><field name="categ_id" colspan="3" nolabel="1"/></div>
                        </group>
                        <group name="properties">
                            <group>
                                <field name="property_account_income" domain="[('type','=','other')]" groups="account.group_account_user"/>
                                <field name="taxes_id" colspan="2" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="property_account_expense" domain="[('type','=','other')]" groups="account.group_account_user"/>
                                <field name="supplier_taxes_id" colspan="2" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </page>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="product_template_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.template.search</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="mode">primary</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="product_variant_ids" position="after">
                    <field name="categ_id"/>
                </field>
                <xpath expr="//group[@string='Group by...']" position="inside">
                    <filter string='Category' icon="terp-stock_symbol-selection" domain="[]" context="{'group_by' : 'categ_id'}"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="view_category_property_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.category.property.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">product.category</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_category_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data>
                    <xpath expr="//group[@name='parent']" position="inside">
                        <group name="account_property" string="Account Properties" colspan="2">
                            <field name="property_account_income_categ" domain="[('type','&lt;&gt;','view'),('type','&lt;&gt;','consolidation')]"/>
                            <field name="property_account_expense_categ" domain="[('type','&lt;&gt;','view'),('type','&lt;&gt;','consolidation')]"/>
                        </group>
                    </xpath>
                </data>
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

and here is the view that inherited previous view and gave me the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="product_config_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.config.form.view</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view" />   
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <label for="name" position="replace">
                    <label for="name" invisible="1"/>
                </label>
                <field name="name" position="replace">                      

                    <div style="font-size:10pt;">
                        <label for="class_id" string="Item Class" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="font-size:10pt;">
                        <field name="class_id" colspan="3" nolabel="1" on_change="onchange_class_id(class_id)"
                        /> </div> 
                    <div style="font-size:10pt;">
                        <label for="name" string="Item Description"/>
                    </div>
                    <div style="font-size:10pt;" >
                        <field name="name" colspan="3" nolabel="1"/>
                    </div>

                </field>
                <field name="default_code" position="replace" >
                    <field name="default_code" string="Item Number" /> 
                </field> 

                <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Accounting']/group" position="replace">
                </xpath>
            </field>        
        </record>

        <record id="product_config_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.config.tree.view</field>
            <field name="model">product.class</field>
            <field name="type">tree</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Product">
                    <field name="default_code" string="Class ID" colspan="3" nolabel="1" />                         
                    <field name="name" string="Class Description" colspan="3" nolabel="1"/>                     
                </tree>
            </field>          
        </record>    

        <record id="class_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">class.search.view</field>
            <field name="model">product.class</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search string="Class">
                    <field name="name" string="Class Description" filter_domain="['|',('default_code','ilike',self),
                    ('name','ilike',self)]" />                                
                </search>
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 2):

You start your xpath expression with `//notebook`.
So your xpath selects all `notebook` elements, regardless of where they appear in the document.
But I don't see any xml tag that contains notebook.

This expression:

```
<xpath expr="//page[@string='Accounting']/group" position="replace"></xpath>
```

selects all the group elements under:

```
<page string="Accounting" groups="account.group_account_invoice">
```

Comment: The issue was the wrong view for inherit_id. Thank you for your help.